# Obtención de Imagen usando SharedExtension

Tags: swift, swift3

Estoy probando un sharedExtension para poder pasar una foto desde la cámara, por ejemplo, a mi app. Hay muchos tutoriales y ejemplos en internet y todos son básicamente iguales, pero a la hora de obtener el fichero da el error Failed to determine whether URL ....is managed by a file provider. 
Tengo creado el certificado con el app group, tengo definido el NSExtension, hasta NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount. Ejecuto el sharedExtension, me abre la galería de fotos, selecciono una, aparece mi sharedExtension para seleccionar, le doy al post y a la hora de que se ejecute el método didSelectPost() es cuando me da este error. Este es mi código:

```
override func didSelectPost() {
    if let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem{
        let contentType = kUTTypeImage as String

        if let contents = item.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] {

            for attachment in contents {
                if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {
                    attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil, completionHandler: { (data, error) in
                        let url = data as! URL
                        if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                            print(imageData)
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)

}
```

Comment: Spidvmp: por favor, intenta revisar las colas con mayor detenimiento. Hoy por ejemplo dijiste que [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/193379/83) no requiere ninguna acción en [esta revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/114407), cuando la pregunta claramente necesita que se le hagan cosas. Cuanto mejor revisemos, mejores respuestas tendremos y mejor nos ayudaremos todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado con un dispositivo físico y el código funciona correctamente. Tiene que ser un bug de Xcode 9.2, que es con el que he probado