# Tengo una pregunta acerca de este error para poder hacer una insercion en el formulario, me marca error la linea del request y no entiendo porque

Tags: java, mvc

```
type Informe de Excepción

mensaje Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /Cliente.jsp en línea 56

descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /Cliente.jsp en línea 56

53:             <tbody>
54:                 <%
55:                     sv.edu.udb.dao.UsuarioDAO ud = new sv.edu.udb.dao.UsuarioDAO();
56:                     request.setAttribute("usuario", ud.findAll());
57:                 %>
58:                 <c:forEach items="${ usuario }" var="usuarios">
59:                     <tr>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:580)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
causa raíz

java.lang.NullPointerException
    sv.edu.udb.model.AppConnection.close(AppConnection.java:48)
    sv.edu.udb.dao.UsuarioDAO.findAll(UsuarioDAO.java:74)
    org.apache.jsp.Cliente_jsp._jspService(Cliente_jsp.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se ve en la traza de error, parece indicar que la conexión de base de datos no está bien configurada:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    sv.edu.udb.model.AppConnection.close(AppConnection.java:48)
    sv.edu.udb.dao.UsuarioDAO.findAll(UsuarioDAO.java:74)
```

Revisa esos dos ficheros (AppConection y UsuarioDAO) en las líneas que te dice la traza